# jQuery .load working randomly, desperate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, load

I've spent an extremely long time trying to figure out why .load in jQuery works really weirdly for me. I have no idea what causes it not to work correctly sometimes.

I am building an UI where the user doesn't have to reload, but instead, whenever they click an `<a>` link, it calls a JS function that loads the url's contents into a "contentLoad" div.

I'm learning coding myself and jQuery & JS is pretty confusing to me, so I try to keep it as simple as possible.

Situation: I am using a simple JS function that takes an URL (from local FTP server), checks whether the URL has any parameters (example.php?abc=...), inserts "?included=1" behind the URL (to prevent it to be opened unless called by this function) and puts the file's contents into an empty DIV using .load (and also uses .load to display a loading page).

Problem is, it works perfectly, but every two minutes or so, it gets stuck on my loading screen and I have to either run the function again or reload the whole thing. I have no idea what's wrong.

Function:

```
var loadPage = function(url)    {
$("#contentLoad").load("loading.php");

if(url.indexOf("?")>=0){
    $("#contentLoad").load(url + "&included=1");
}
else {
    $("#contentLoad").load(url + "?included=1");
}
window.history.replaceState('Object', 'Title', url);
}
```

Then, when I want to have an `<a>` that opens the page "explore.php", for example, I use

`<li><a href="#" onclick="loadPage('explore.php')">Explore</a></li>`.

What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: If the issue is transient my first port of call would be look at the network/server side of things. Can you expand on the local FTP server part? That sounds very non-typical.. (Offtopic: I see far worse questions from people twice your age, keep up the good work!)

Comment: Did you try using anything like Firebug to see if the request is even being made during the times when it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I simply have a cheap remote FTP server, and the files I'm trying to .load are in the same directory, that's what I meant.

Anyways, I don't really know how this worked but I suppose the two .loads sort of "blocked each other out", because now that I removed the .load of the loading page, it works... Wow, haha.

So my solution was just replacing the "$("#contentLoad").load("loading.php");" with "document.getElementById("contentLoad").innerHTML = 'loading...';"

Thanks a lot for the compliment, though :)

Comment: Also, to Hanky - I checked out the Network section of the Chrome Dev Tools. The request is made, but there's no reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright so, I don't really know how this worked but I suppose the two .loads sort of "blocked each other out", because now that I removed the .load of the loading page, it works... Wow, haha.

So my solution was just replacing the

`$("#contentLoad").load("loading.php");`

with

```
document.getElementById("contentLoad").innerHTML = 'loading...';
```

Thanks to you guys for the help, though! :)

Comment: Just want to encourage you to keep programming. Here is your 1st up-vote on an answer on SO. Your code is simple and simplicity is genius, at 12 you are doing good. Way to go :)

Comment: I want to echo what @Hanky웃Panky said and also explain a little bit what happened as I understand it. You're right in that it's quite possible the two .load() calls were conflicting. What likely happened is the request from the first .load (to the loading screen) actually completed *after* the call to the second .load(). This happened due to a very important aspect of Javascript called ["asynchronous programming"](http://tech.pro/blog/1402/five-patterns-to-help-you-tame-asynchronous-javascript) - I strongly encourage you to read about it if you want to go deeper on Javascript :) keep it up!

Comment: Thanks a ton for the link, I suppose that's what happened! I'll study about it a bit more. Nevertheless, thanks a lot to both of you, and the motivation :)